# Create global vector using LLVM IR Builder

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I want to build up LLVM IR for the following expression to add a scalar to a vector

```
[1,2,3,4]+1
```

I have found the correct methods to create the add and the scalar expression but not for the vector.

```
Value *L = //Missing code here
Value *R = ConstantFP::get(getGlobalContext(), APFloat(Val));
Value *exp = Builder.CreateFAdd(L, R, "addresult");
```

How can I generate this vector?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you actually need a [vector](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#t-vector) i.e. a datatype on which you can operate in parallel (SIMD/SIMT fashion) and not a simple [array](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#array-type).

After that make also sure the type you intend to use is right (APFloat is arbitrary precision float).

Creating a vector can proceed in the same way you add elements via [insertelement](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#insertelement-instruction)

```
  Type* u32Ty = Type::getInt32Ty( llvmContext );
  Type* vecTy = VectorType::get(u32Ty, 4);
  Value* emptyVec = UndefValue::get(vecTy);
  Constant* index0 =  Constant::getIntegerValue(u32Ty, llvm::APInt(32, 0));
  Value* insert1 = InsertElementInst(/*First integer value*/, emptyVec, index0, 0);
```

Comment: Yes, I want to use vector to take advantage of SIMD.

Comment: I want the IRBuilder to produce IR like this: @veca = global [5 x i32] [i32 1, i32 2, i32 3, i32 4, i32 5]

Comment: Then the code above will do it just fine. Insert the elements and you'll be good to go.